# How to put XML into my SoapClient Call using a Method

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have generated some XML which is saved to a file.

```
Dummy_Order.xml
```

In the following code I wanted to open the XML and use it in the method 'ImpOrders'

Here is my code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://soapclient/wsdl/Web?wsdl', array ('trace' => 1));

if (file_exists('Dummy_Order.xml')) {
    $xml = file_get_contents('Dummy_Order.xml');
} else {
  exit('Failed to open XML.');
}

$xmlstring = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$result = $proxy->ImportOrders($xmlstring);

var_dump($result);
echo "REQUEST:\n" . $proxy->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
?>
```

I am getting a response in $result of 0 imported 0 skipped. So i then did getLastRequest() and it's adding the code from the Method but not adding my XML. It wants my XML in a string - which it current is in and isnt moaning about that (It does moan if i use it ->asXML).

I have tried

```
$result = $proxy->ImportOrders();
```

and

```
$result = $proxy->ImportOrders($xmlstring);
```

And both show the same result in _getLastRequest, which led me to believe that my string isn't being plugged in.

When I check the functions using _getFunctions it provides the information of this...

```
ImportResult ImportOrders(string $Orders)
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: do you got any errors

Comment: not from Soap just 0 imported etc as the request is a the template request with no field filled in from my XML file

Comment: It seems that XMLstring returns false when plugged into is_string - maybe this is my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i resolved it. All i needed to do was wrap my answer in <<

Like below.

```
$teststring = <<<XML
$xml
XML;

$result = $proxy->ImportOrders($teststring);
```

Hope this helps out anyone else using PHP, SoapClient and XML.